# Converting .htaccess to IIRF

Tags: .htaccess, iirf

I'm trying to convert to IIRF, but it's just not working.
The IIRF documentation is not very helpful.

Original code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/]+)$ ?g=$1 [L]
```

I tried adding slashes, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

The Options +FollowSymlinks is breaking your IIRF. You can ignore it, since windows does not use symlinks.